# Why file_get_contents() returns “failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!”? HTTP/1.0 429 Unknown

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents, http-status-code-429

I am having problems with file_get_contents. I needed to get contents from this url: http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=P250%20|%20Valence%20(Field-Tested)

Works good when i open it with my browser, my php script:

`$item = "P250 | Valence (Field-Tested)"; 
 $link = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name='.urlencode($item);
echo file_get_contents($link);`

Throws me this error:
 `Warning: file_get_contents(http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=P250+%7C+Valence+%28Field-Tested%29): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 429 Unknown`

Comment: There is a ddos protection for website, that's why... You can use curl php.

Comment: @Bbbb Is that the same as using `curl <url>`?  And why does curl work here and file_get_contents() does not?

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you are receiving from Steam's servers a `429` HTTP error :

```
429 Too Many Requests (RFC 6585)
The user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time. Intended for use with rate limiting schemes.
```

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)